# SimpleModal with scrollbar script

Tags: jquery, scroll, simplemodal, scroller

I am using SimpleModal script. Also I want to display in it a special DIV tag with long text. This DIV need to have his own scrollbar.

Sample code: www.sildev.pl/basic/index.html
You can download this from here: www.sildev.pl/basic.zip

As You can see it's working standalone, but together it crushes. Why? Can anybody fix it to me?

Regards,
Piotr.

EDIT:

I made this changes, but still got problem with project. It is very strange for me. Can you look at this again?

Updated version: www.sildev.pl/basic/index.html

ZIP: www.sildev.pl/basic.zip

How to make this scroll works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have display none for `<div id="basic-modal-content">`

if you change in basic.js this line (line 21):

```
$('#basic-modal-content').modal();
```

to

```
$('#demo4').modal();
```

it will work

**updates:**

*changes line 14 in **basic.css** file:*

---from: `#basic-modal-content {display:none;}`

---to  `#basic-modal-content {visibility:hidden;}`

Comment: Thx. Can you look at my post one more time? I made update links.

Comment: changes line 14 in "basic.css" file:

---from:      "  #basic-modal-content {display:none;} "

---to         "  #basic-modal-content {visibility:hidden;} "